# Postgresql jsonb column to row extracted values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the below table

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public".appevents (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    "eventId" uuid NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    "creationTime" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "creationTimeInMilliseconds" bigint NOT NULL,
    metadata jsonb NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

COMMIT;
```

I would like to extract with a query the `metadata` jsonb column as a row and tried with the below query.

```
SELECT 
    userId
FROM 
    appevents, jsonb_to_record(appevents.metadata) as x(userId text)
```

Unfortunately, all the rows returned for `userid` have the value NULL which is not true. The only weird thing noticed is that it is converting camelcase to lowercase but doesn't seem like the issue.

[image: Results_Rows]

Here are the 2 records I currently have in the database where `userId` exists.

[image: Records]

Comment: Try `x("userId" text)`

Comment: Much simpler: `SELECT metadata->>'userId' AS userid FROM appevents`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @Bergi I think your solution is much simpler and thank you, only problem is I have to go through all key/value pairs but it's OK.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually didn't add that, I exported the script from the client I use, I will try to recreate the table without the quoted identifiers. I assume you're talking about the column names;

Comment: @Bergi feel free to post an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only weird thing noticed is that it is converting camelcase to lowercase but doesn't seem like the issue.

Actually that is the culprit - column names are case-insensitive by default, and `userId` is normalised to `userid`, for which the JSON doesn't contain a property. Quoting the identifier (`… as x("userId" text)`) should work.

However, there's a much simpler solution for accessing json object properties as text: the `->>` operator. You can use

```
SELECT metadata->>'userId' AS userid FROM appevents
```